# My breakpoints won't work with Eclipse Mars 2

Tags: eclipse

All of a sudden my breakpoints won't work for my Eclipse Mars project.

I set them - and it even asks if you want to go to debug perspective when the app gets to a breakpoint - but you can't actually see it stop at the breakpoint.  It's like it's stopping - but you can't see the highlighted lines.

I've tried cleaning everything out and re-building multiple times.  Still the same.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that can happen when your disk space is extremely low.